# How put string to Shared Preference?

Tags: java, android, string, sharedpreferences

Could anybody help me, please? I have this code:

```
Process a;
try {
    a = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su"); 

    DataOutputStream swp = new DataOutputStream(a.getOutputStream());
    swp.writeBytes("cat /proc/sys/vm/blabla\n");
    swp.writeBytes("exit\n"); 
    swp.flush();
    try {
        a.waitFor();
        if (a.exitValue() != 255) {
            // TODO Code to run on success
            toastMessage("root");
            }
        else {
            // TODO Code to run on unsuccessful             
           toastMessage("not root");
           }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Code to run in interrupted exception    
        toastMessage("not root");
        }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Code to run in input/output exception
    toastMessage("not root");
}
```

This code `swp.writeBytes("cat /proc/sys/vm/blabla\n");` copies text (string) from system file called "blabla". And then I need to put this text (String) to my SharedPreferences. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this was your code, you should know. In case you don't, you can [follow the Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

In your case, you'll want to use the [`putString()`-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

---

To get what `cat` printed out, you'll need the output of your `Process`-object. Use the [`getInputStream()`-method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream%28%29).

Comment: I know how to putString to SharedPreferences, but in this case it's more cmplicate. The problem is in cat command. Could you give some example?